# Bcash não funciona com Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Estou tentando utilizar um código de carrinho do bcash no meu site, porém pelo que eu percebi, ele não funciona quando o site utiliza jquery. Tentei num site com html puro e o link abriu normal, porém com jquery não acontece nada. Alguem sabe o que pode ser?

```
<!-- INÍCIO DO CÓDIGO BCASH cod. produto bkp1 -->
<form action='https://www.bcash.com.br/checkout/car/' id="form_id" method='post' target='carrinho'>
<input type='hidden' value='add' name='acao'>
<input type='hidden' value='teste@teste.com' name='email_loja'> 
<input type='hidden' value='123' name='cod_prod'>
<input type='hidden' value='nome_teste' name='nome_prod'>
<input type='hidden' value='67.90' name='valor_prod'>
<input type='hidden' value='0' name='peso_prod'>
<table border='0'><tr><td valign='middle'>
Quant.: <br />&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='text' maxLength='3' size='2' value='1' name='quant_prod' style='text-align:center'></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td><td><font size='1' color='#FF0000'>Frete Grátis</font><br />
<input type='image' src='https://www.bcash.com.br/webroot/img/banking/bt_adicionar_ao_carrinho.gif'  id="enviadadoscliente" value='Adicionar ao Carrinho' alt='Adicionar ao Carrinho' border='0' align='absbottom' /></td></tr></table></form>
<!-- FIM DO CÓDIGO BCASH cod. produto bkp1 -->
```

Tentei utilizar o seguinte código abaixo em javascript para tentar forçar a abertura, mas também nada:

```
 $(function(){
    $("#enviadadoscliente").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#form_id").submit();
    });
});
```

Obrigado desde já pela ajuda.

Comment: Onde está $('enviadadoscliente') deve ser $('#enviadadoscliente').

Comment: Olá jefersondaniel. Na verdade eu realmente escrevi errado aqui, mas em meu código está correto, e não é esta a causa. Obrigado.

Comment: Mas precisa do evento `onclick` para submeter o formulário? Pois o `type="image"` naturalmente age como um `type="submit"`. Não faz sentido desativar o recurso padrão de "submit"  e ao mesmo tempo atribuir uma função de "submit".

Comment: Daniel, conforme expliquei no tópico, o problema é que o botão não funciona devido ao Jquery. Sem o Jquery ele funciona normalmente. Porém com ele não funciona. Então eu tentei utilizar essa função para ver se funcionaria, mas também sem sucesso. Apenas quis colocá-la junto no tópico para enriquecer, mas não necessariamente é a forma correta.